# Tolerant Sum of column

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to make the sum of a column which might also contain cells which are not parseable as a number (strings, empty, etc). These cells should just be ignored.

I've tried:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A500,"<>0")
```

but it doesn't work because it also seems to exclude cells which actually contain valid numbers.

Is there a better way of performing a summation, excluding none parseable values?

Comment: =sum(A1:A500). Sum will ignore all cells that are not parseable as number.

Comment: @JPV: it will not ignore cells with @VALUE! . but with the "<>0" this is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me add my comment as an answer... :-)

You should be okay just using =SUM(), because sum() simply ignores non-numeric values.

Comment: actually my problem is that some cells contain an error resulting from another bad calculation. so they show #VALUE! but this can be fixed by using SUMIF instead of SUM

Comment: I usually wrap the other calculation in an IFERROR() so that errors are not shown. Then SUM() should work.